# How I can give the app in Android like "Redeem code" of Apple

Tags: android, google-play

How I can give the app in Android like "Redeem code" of Apple.

In Apple's do it from the developer account and Google can not.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best way would be to keep the code on a server and check to see of the unput code matches any code on the server. AFAIK there isnt really a way to implement such a thing in the play store